# Find the highest value of a vector with boxplot.stats function

Tags: r, boxplot

I have an issue with a boxplot. I'm using a function called get_box_values() and I don't understand why it can find the highest value of my vector.

```
require(stats)

get_box_values <- function(x) {
  boxplot.stats(x)$stats %>% t() %>% cbind(round(mean(x),1)) %>% cbind(boxplot.stats(x)$n) %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
    setNames(c("low", "q1", "median", "q3", "high", "mean", "obs"))
}

# With myvec, it's ok
myvec <- c(5,10,20,100,50)
get_box_values(myvec)
```

[image]

```
# With myvec2, it doesn't work for the highest value (154401)
myvec2 <- c(26195,25086,154401,35287,13500)
get_box_values(myvec2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because 154401 in `myvec2` is considered an outlier.

```
boxplot.stats(myvec2)$out
#[1] 154401
```

Comment: OK, thanks. Is there a way not to consider it as an outlier with boxplot.stats() ?

Comment: There might be but why not use `summary` function instead? `summary(myvec2)`. Also `fivenum(myvec2)`

Comment: ok great, it work with `boxplot.stats(myvec2,coef=0)$stats`